# Magento 1 order creation with disabled produt via soap API

Tags: soap

I'm using Magento 1.7 and I want to create an order via magento SOAP API with "disabled" product in it.

### Is it possible?

Code:

```
// create order
echo "\nI will create the order: ";
$resultOrderCreation = $proxy->call($sessionId,"cart.order",array($shoppingCartId, null, $licenseForOrderCreation));
echo "\nOrder created with code:".$resultOrderCreation."\n";
```

Here is the error trace:

> I will create the order:
>
> Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to
> a member function getId() on a non-object in test2.php:175 Stack
> trace:
>
> ## 0 test2.php(175): SoapClient->__call('call', Array)
>
> ## 1 test2.php(175): SoapClient->call('6e2ee08630a720a...', 'cart.order', Array)
>
> ## 2 {main}   thrown in test2.php on line 175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal::_initItem.
Specifically row with code:

```
if (!$product || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
    return false;
}
```

Remove/Customize !$product->isVisibleInCatalog().